# Trigger Snowflake task after Fivetran completed loading

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to start a Snowflake data loading **task** **automatically** after loading data via Fivetran completed that **does not involve** creating a task that runs every x minutes, polling Fivetran's metadata to validate whether to continue or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggered tasks are currently not available (for Fivetran or other means). I think it's a great feature request though so please feel free to submit an Idea here so other can vote for it for potential inclusion in a future release: https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas

Comment: I also had a colleague make a suggestion which is still task-related, but if the metadata is granular enough, you might be able to use a stream on the Fivetran metadata to reduce the invocations of the task.

Comment: Do you mean by using  SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA @suzy-lockwood? See https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-pipelines-intro.html

Comment: @RogierWerschkull Something like that was my assumption when my colleague mentioned it, but I must admit I haven't personally tested it. I'll welcome comments from others if they have.